How to obtain reference to array instead of slice?
I have an array of 4 X u32 types. I would like a reference to the array (pointer) instead of a slice (pointer + length). The snippet below prints 16 for both slice and reference which suggests that both forms of initialization are returning a slice.
Is there some syntax for returning a reference to the array that isn't a slice?
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let array: [u32; 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let slice: &[u32] = &array[..];
    let reference: &[u32; 4] = &array;
    println!("size(slice)     = {:?}", mem::size_of_val(slice)); // Prints: 16
    println!("size(reference) = {:?}", mem::size_of_val(reference)); // Prints: 16
}

rust playground

No. size_of_val() returns the size of the value pointed by the reference, which is the same for arrays and slices. If you will do size_of_val(&reference), you will see reference is a thin pointer.
